# Get callbacks argument list

Tags: php, callback

I have this:

```
a( function ( $x, $y )
{
    // ...
});

function a( $callback )
{
    // get $callback's arguments: "$x", "$y"
}
```

How can I get `$callback` arguments (`$x` and `$y`) in `function a(...)` ?

When I do: `var_dump( $callback )` inside `function a(...)` then it shows me:

```
object(Closure)#1 (1) {
  ["parameter"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["$x"]=>
    string(10) "<required>"
    ["$y"]=>
    string(10) "<required>"
  }
}
```

Which is exactly what I need. I just dont know what function I should call to retrieve Array of `$callback`'s arguments.

Comment: `$callback->parameter`? Does that work?

Comment: @Neal I've already tried it. No luck: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Closure object cannot have properties`